# Comparing specific row in a column with all columns for that specific row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and been trying to figure this out for a week now

I have a dataset 2 rows by 2000ish columns, the data came in a dictionary format and I used df.DataFrame to convert it (Don't know if this is helpful or not)

Here is an example

```
          gene1  gene2  gene3 etc

 location [1,2]  [3,4]  [5,6]
 enhancer ATCG   GGGG   CATA
```

I want to compare the enhancer from gene 1 to the enhancer for the rest of the genes one by one to tell me how many differences there are between them. I know I can't make a new column for this since won't work, I think the best solution is to save the new information to a new Data frame

Example output

```
             gene1   gene 2  gene3 
difference     0       3       4
```

I would like an idea on how to approach this from a different perspective, I've tried doing it by using nested loop but couldn't figure it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely not the best way to do that, but I would try the following as it is the most straight-forward to me.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"gene1":[[1,2],"ATCG"],
                   "gene2":[[3,4],"GGGG"],
                   "gene3":[[5,6],"CATA"]},index=["location","enhancer"])
target_gene = df.loc["enhancer","gene1"]
df.loc["difference",:] = list(map(lambda x:sum([c1!=c2 for (c1,c2) in zip(x,target_gene)]), 
                                  df.loc["enhancer",:]))
df
```

[image]